# Why does core-list doesn't set a height within a core-header-panel?

Tags: polymer

I've tried to put a `<core-list>` into a `<core-header-panel>` but the core-list is not rendered until I give it a height.

So my example code does work with a very silly hack, but I think there must be better way to **fit** the  core-list into the page.

**The structure is as follows:**

[image]

Here's my code:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gu0g8kt3/2/

**HTML**

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">

<core-drawer-panel>
  <core-header-panel drawer>
    <core-image style="width:256px; height:170px; background-color: lightgray;"
                sizing="cover" preload fade src="http://lorempixel.com/256/170/abstract/"></core-image>

      <core-menu selectedAttribute="">
      <paper-item>
        <core-icon icon="assignment"></core-icon>
        <div>Option #1</div>
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item>
        <core-icon icon="account-circle"></core-icon>
        <div>Option #2</div>
      </paper-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>

  <core-header-panel id="hPanel" main>
    <core-toolbar id="toolbar">
      <paper-menu-button icon="menu" core-drawer-toggle></paper-menu-button>
      <span flex>This is my app!</span>
    </core-toolbar>

    <div class="content">


      <!-- here is the problem -->        
      <core-list id="list" height="120">
        <template>
            <div class="row {{ { selected: selected } | tokenList }}">
                <div flex><core-image style="width:40px; height:40px; background-color: lightgray;" src="{{model.image_src}}" sizing="cover" preload></core-image></div>
            </div>
        </template>
       </core-list>
       <paper-fab class="fab" icon="add"></paper-fab>


    </div>

  </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

**CSS**

```
core-header-panel {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.fab {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
}

/* main area content */
core-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 200px; /* this is just a bad workaround, must be > 0 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px #dedede solid;
}

.selected {
  background: orange;
}

/* drawer content */
core-toolbar {
  color: #2c2c2c;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #d5d5d5, 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; }

core-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -4px; }
  core-menu paper-item {
    border-bottom: 1px grey solid; }
    core-menu paper-item > div {
      padding-left: 10px !important; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    data.push({
        image_src: 'http://lorempixel.com/40/40/business/?' + Math.round(Math.random()*100)
    });
}

document.querySelector('#list').data = data;

// the only way it works for me is the following:
var mainPanel = document.querySelector('#hPanel');
var toolbar = document.querySelector('#toolbar');
var list = document.querySelector('#list');

var contentHeight = mainPanel.clientHeight - toolbar.clientHeight;
list.style.height = contentHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in this comment, core-list needs some help to be sized properly: https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/47#issuecomment-63126241

I was able to fix your jsfiddle with two changes:

1. give 'fit' layout to content div, so it will fill entire remaining area in  hPanel:

> ```
> <div class="content" fit>
> ```

2. give 100% height to the list

> ```
>  <core-list id="list" height="120" style="height:100%;" >
> ```

With these changes, setting height for the list in javascript is not necessary.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ktwg9kk/

Comment: Thanks for this. But is there any "real" way to make this work so that the scrolling is done on the actual "content" area and not the list itself?

Comment: @user2422321 there is scrollTarget property for using something other than the list itself for generating scroll events: https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/blob/master/core-list.html#L160

it says it's 'experimental' though, no idea if it will work for you

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot for that! I might have worded what I was after a bit bad though. As it is right now, the list is technically limited by the visible area (and therefore causing the scrolling list), would it be possible for the list to actually expand it's own container so that the "content"-page itself is expanded (and therefore the scrolling will automatically occur on the content-page)?

Comment: @user2422321 No I don't think it's possible, one big core-list assumption is that it's height is fixed: https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/blob/master/core-list.html#L23 
This component is intended to handle big lists (100k items), so it creates DOM only for items that are actually visible or 'not too far' from being visible, to do that it needs to know container height, and it won't expand it.

Comment: Thanks a lot artem, really appreciate your explanation! I will use a simple repeat in the content-area instead (since i won't have that many items :P)!