# How to set 100% height on polymer core-list in paper-tabs

Tags: css, polymer

I'm trying to make 100% height on `core-list` element placed in `<paper-tabs>` in polymer. 
Unfortunately when I'm tryng to solve my problem with comment from this link [StackOverflow Height on Core-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251551/why-does-core-list-doesnt-set-a-height-within-a-core-header-panel) my core list gets 80px height and I'm not able to set height bigger value.

My code below:

```
<polymer-element name="progress-page" attributes="hash">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/menu-card.css">
    <sidebar-layout selected="main-page">
        <div class="title">Report</div>
        <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
            <div class="page-sub-title">Progress</div>
        </div>


        <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
            <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>

        <core-pages  selected="{{selected}}">
            <div>
                <div class="content" fit style="overflow:auto;">
                    <core-list data="{{data}}" fit height="120" style=" height: 100%;">
                        <template>
                            <div class="row" layout horizontal center>
                                <div data-index="{{index}}">{{model.name}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </core-list>
                </div>
             </div>

                <div>
                    Page 2 qasdasd
                </div>
        </core-pages>


    </sidebar-layout>


</template>

<script>
    Polymer('progress-page', {
        ready: function () {
            this.selected = 0;
            this.data = generateContacts();

            function generateContacts() {
                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        name: 'dddd',
                        string: 'asd'
                    });
                }
                return data;
            };
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried second solution and this still doesn't work , code below. I have to make height in pixels to see core list , can somebody please help me ?

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-list/core-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">


<polymer-element name="progress-page" attributes="hash">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
                height: 100%;
            }
            core-list .row {
                height: 90px;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/menu-card.css">
        <sidebar-layout selected="main-page">
            <div class="title">Report</div>
            <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                <div class="page-sub-title">Progress</div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                <section layout vertical is="auto-binding">
                    <paper-tabs selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" horizontal center layout>
                        <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout active>Terazniejszy miesiac</paper-tab>
                        <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout>Archiwum</paper-tab>
                    </paper-tabs>
                    <core-animated-pages selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" notap>
                        <section active one fit layout style="height:auto;">
                            <list-test layout vertical>
                            <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                                <p class="progress-title">Summary</p>


                            </div>

                            <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                                <div class="page-holder progress-sumarry-color " horizontal layout center
                                     center-justified>
                                    <div>Month</div>
                                    <div flex>+ x persons</div>
                                    <div>+ x points</div>
                                </div>
                           </div>


                            <core-list id="app" data="{{data}}" height="80" style="will-change: transform; overflow-y: auto;height:1000px;">
                                <template>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        List row: {{index}}, User data from model: {{model.name}}
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{model.checked}}">
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </core-list>





                            </list-test>
                        </section>
                        <section one flex horizontal layout>

                        </section>

                    </core-animated-pages>
                </section>
            </div>
        </sidebar-layout>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('progress-page', {
                    ready: function () {
                        selected: 0;
                        var app = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("app");
                        app.data = generateContacts();
                        var template = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("templ");

                        function generateContacts() {
                            var data = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < 88; i++) {
                                data.push({
                                    name: 'dddd',
                                    string: 'asd',
                                    cardID: 'icard-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1) + 1)
                                });
                            }
                            return data;
                        };
                    },
                    handleResponse: function (oldValue) {
                        if (this.response == 1) {

                        }
                        else {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("hash", '');
                            document.querySelector('app-router').go('/login?error=tokenTimeout');
                        }


                    },
                }
        );
    </script>
</polymer-element>
<progress-page></progress-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your core-list fit to it's parent element which is a selected page with div element under core pages. Make sure you set the right size to it's parent.

Comment: It is not working , can you please look to my second code that i wrote ?
I still have to make height with pixels , when I make 100% or height: auto  core list is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try with this css:

```
:host {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

for more info about vh you can read here: [VH & co. CSS](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Comment: I'm still having error:  core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized

Answer (score 0):

Tyhoan is right, you should check the size of the parent elements.
For example just adding a `style="height:100%;"` to each of core-list parents (from your second solution) seems to work:

```
<div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified style="height:100%;">
            <section layout vertical is="auto-binding" style="height:100%;">

                <paper-tabs selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" horizontal center layout>
                    <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout active>Terazniejszy miesiac</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab inline flex center-center horizontal layout>Archiwum</paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>

                <core-animated-pages selected="{{ selected }}" selectedindex="0" notap style="height:100%;">
                    <section active one fit layout vertical>

                        <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                            <p class="progress-title">Summary</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="page-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                            <div class="page-holder progress-sumarry-color " horizontal layout center
                                 center-justified>
                                <div>Month</div>
                                <div flex>+ x persons</div>
                                <div>+ x points</div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div style="height:100%;">
                        <core-list id="app" data="{{data}}" style="height:100%;">
                            <template>
                                <div class="row">
                                    List row: {{index}}, User data from model: {{model.name}}
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{model.checked}}">
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </core-list>
                        </div>

                    </section>
                    <section one flex horizontal layout>

                    </section>

                </core-animated-pages>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Comment: I't almost work , I dont have error now but my content div has 40px of height, is there any way to fix it ?